# UITableViewCells not creating properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using Storyboard to create UITableView, but when creating customised cells it's not creating properly. See this below screen

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6776t.png)

In this screen another new view appearing in white colour. This is happing only in Swift. I clearly checked there is only two labels in my prototype cell. There is no third view.

My code is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCellClass
    cell.permissionClassTitleLbl.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.permissionClassDescLbl.text = descArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.permissionClassDescLbl.numberOfLines = 0

    //        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return cell

}
```

My storyboard ViewController screen is.

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHkeK.png)

[image: ![enter image description here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PB1f.png)

But when i write **cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue** this code this third view disappears. Why the reason i don't know. See this below screen

[image: ![enter image description here]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XbaD.png)

I'm using Single TableViewCell class for all TableViewCell in my entire project.

Comment: Can you add picture of your prototype table view cell in storyboard?

Comment: Please wait.....

Comment: Cell-ContentView-Your custom labels

Comment: check your cell. i think you add view or something else  in celll

Comment: @ Robert Dresler I updated my question with more screens please see this

Comment: @Maulik shah  already I double checked and I added screen my third image in the above question. in that there is no another view .

Comment: @ Robert Dresler I added my two labels to in this order    cell -> ContentView -> Lbl1 and Lbl2

Comment: And can you add your code where you have connected these labels?

Comment: @Robert Dresler in TableViewCell class, this is common class to all my TableViews for entire project. In that so many TableViewCells properties are there. But I'm accessing only these two only.

Comment: Maybe in this common class you this extra view and you don’t hide it

Comment: @ Robert Dresler absolutely you are right, I'm re sizing cell.imageView and cell.textLabel. Thats why it's displaying. Thank you very much to spent your valuable time for me.

Comment: Set the hieght of the row  using "heightForRowAt" method

Comment: @iOS have you tried using View Hierarchy Debugger to see what is this white rectangle?